# Query and sort on nultiple collections based on time

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Our application is planning to use MongoDB for reports.
Our reports are time-based (where the raw data is different events).
We were thinking of creating a separate collection for each day, so we will not need to query a whole large collection when we need to query,aggregate and sort events for a specific day only.
One question is whether this design makes sense.
Another question is what will happen if we need to aggregate and sort event over more than one collection - for one week for example.
Does MongoDB supports this? If it does - how should it be done so it will be efficient n terms of performance?

Answer (score 0):

> We were thinking of creating a separate collection for each day, so we will not need to query a whole large collection when we need to query,aggregate and sort events for a specific day only.
>   One question is whether this design makes sense.

While using proper indexes, mongoDB should not have problems with a very big collection.
You could read more here: [MongoDB indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/)

> Another question is what will happen if we need to aggregate and sort event over more than one collection - for one week for example.
>   Does MongoDB supports this? If it does - how should it be done so it will be efficient n terms of performance?

If you want to go your way, you could use aggregation pipelines and [`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) to run multiple queries at once. However this could become a little tricky because you have to generate the collection names from your query parameters. Infact, i think this could be slower and more prone to errors. So i don't recomend this approach.

Comment: Thanks! will take this into account

Comment: Glad to hear that! Give me an upvote if my answer was helpful for you. Thanks!